# Отправка XML POST запросом на C#

Tags: c#, xml, post

Есть у меня задачка. Необходимо отправлять и принимать ответы от веб-сервиса. Вот данные из инструкции.

> Request and response information is transmitted by placing an XML
>   document in the POST payload of the HTTPS request. To integrate with
>   the iCRS system, do the following:
>   1. Build/Use a client program that can operate with the HTTPS protocol. There are no restrictions on the type of client program
>   used, providing it can use this protocol and deal with transactions
>   synchronously.
>   2. Build/Use a program that can build a valid request XML document (see specification in Appendix A) and attach it via a POST parameter
>   to a HTTPS request. POST / HTTP/1.0 UserAgent:
>   HTTPTool/1.0 ContentType: text/xml Post Payload
>   3. Build/Use a program that can retrieve the HTTPS response and process the binary file output, which includes the XML payload and
>   attached digital signature. See the Extracting the XML Output section
>   on page 9.
>   4. Build/Use a program that can correctly interpret the inquiry response information within the XML return.

Т.е. на сколько я понял, необходимо создать XML и обычным POST запросом отправить, и получить ответ?

XML делаю обычным XElement

```
XElement xml = new XElement("Product",
  new XElement("prequest",
    new XElement("req",
      new XElement("AddressReq",
        new XElement("street", "Горького"),
        new XElement("houseNumber", "1"),
        new XElement("apartment", "38"),
        new XElement("city", "Магадан"),
        new XElement("postal", "685000"),
        new XElement("addressType", "1")))));
```

Далее делаю запрос и ответ:

```
Console.WriteLine(xml);
Console.ReadKey();
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://websevice.com/url");
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(xml.ToString());
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream data = request.GetRequestStream();
data.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
data.Close();
Console.ReadKey();

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
data = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
reader.Close();
data.Close();
response.Close();
Console.ReadKey();
```

Вопрос. Правильно ли я все делаю?

Comment: А вы сами проверяли? Какой ответ приходит?

Comment: @Kirill'luridSNK'F. Да, я пробовал. Соединение происходит, но в ответ получаю:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" standalone="yes"?> <product> <preply> <err> <ctErr> <Code>002</Code> <Text>General System Error: Java.lang.NullPointerException</Text> –

Comment: `<Code>002</Code> <Text>General System Error: Java.lang.NullPointerException</Text>` - вам ничего не говорит?
Это я к тому, что проблема вряд ли с Вашим запросом

Comment: @Kirill'luridSNK'F. Ну я подразумеваю что либо у меня в XML есть пустые поля, либо туда ничего не приходит.

Comment: Учитывая, что вы запускаете данный проект в консольном приложении (судя по написанному коду), вам ничего не мешает проверить свой запрос перед отправкой, простым `console.writeline` текста вашего запроса.

Comment: @Kirill'luridSNK'F. Я вывел в консоль свой XDOC, который создал. Но в нем отсутствует заголовок xml <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" ?>. Хотя я прописывал new XDeclaration("1.0", "Windows-1251","yes"). Я сохранил byte[] в бинарный файл, но там тоже нет заголовка(